# Handle Exception in Class Library with Attribute

Tags: c#, error-handling

In a class Library, I am trying to handle exception with Attributes in Class Library. Is there a way to do without AOP (PostSharp) ?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class HandleError : Attribute
{

    public void OnException(){
    try {

    }
    catch (Exception) {

    }}
}
```

And I want to decorate attribute like this.

```
[HandleError]
public void SampleMethod()
{
  throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: You're about to take the Reflection Gun and aim it at your foot...

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser What does it meant? Please be meaningful

Comment: Simply put, you can't easily. You could use AOP from another library (for example Spring.NET). The only difference would be that Spring.NET works at runtime, while Postsharp works at compile time.

Comment: You could even use Fody to do some code rewriting at compile time, like PostSharp.

Comment: Note that if you simply want to do some logging, and not to really catch the exception, then you could simply add a [FirstChanceException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception.aspx) handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you can't easily. You could use AOP from another library ([for example Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html)). The only difference would be that Spring.NET works at runtime, while Postsharp works at compile time.

You could even use [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) to do some code rewriting at compile time, like PostSharp.

Note that if you simply want to do some logging on an exception and you don't need to remove the exception from the stack (you don't want to "eat" it or change it), then you could simply add a [FirstChanceException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception.aspx) handler. Note that this would slow quite much everything, because you would need to use reflection to check for the presence of the attribute. And if you wanted to walk the stack it would become even slower! (and much more complex)

Comment: Thanks and What will you suggest for handling exception in class library? Do I need to use try/catch in all method blocks?

Comment: @sss Normally I would let "system" exceptions "escape" my library and go to the caller. If I create a library that does http communication, and I get an exception from the underlying TCP class, then I'll let the caller get this exception. I don't like "masking" exceptions with other exceptions.