# Exception Attribute for Class library

Tags: c#, exception, attributes, class-library

My service class has many methods, which call other service and this service has specified exceptions. I want to throw my exception when method catch this specified exception.

I.e.

```
try
{
    // call other service
}
catch(ServiceXxxException serviceEx)
{
    throw new MyException(...);
}
```

but I have many such methods and I don't want to grow code. Is it possible to create exception attribute like `ExceptionFilterAttribute` for ASP.NET MVC/Core ?

Comment: An attribute won't have any affect without some code that processes the attribute.  You're essentially stuck with what you have, though you could refactor it into a common method, which could, for example, take a `Func<T>` or `Action<T>` parameter that does the real work, and wraps it in an exception handler.

Comment: Take a look at Fody. Pretty sure there's an Exception weaver of some sort. Though this is more advanced stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can create general filter to handle any exception may occur and you can use filter attribute to handle, you can use it within the controller or action,  something like this :

```
CustomExceptionFilter]  
public class HomeController:Controller 
{  
   //......  
}  


//Over the Action  
[CustomExceptionFilter]  
public ActionResult Index() 
{  
   //.......  
}
```

please follow this article :

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0ef46a/exception-filters-in-mvc/

Comment: I know, how it works for MVC, I want to have attributes for Class Library

Comment: Not easy, possible Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149577/handle-exception-in-class-library-with-attribute